# Does "local mxxx = require('Module:xxx/xxx')" need to be hardcoded?

Tags: lua

As title, do I need to hardcode module what I want to use? Or it can be dynamic based on User input?
For example there is 30+ (Storage modules) they are big, and I don't want to load them all if at a time only 1 of them will be used.

Can I make something like this:

```
local p = {};

local mTag = require('Module:xxx/frame.args[1]')

[..Code..]

return p
```

Answer (score 1):

No, your code can be dynamic. You are only loading code here, and loading code can happen any time. Notice that require caches your modules. Since you mentioned storage, you may want to use dofile directly. Depends on the task and memory requirements.

> Lua offers a higher-level function to load and run libraries, called require. Roughly, require does the same job as dofile, but with two important differences. First, require searches for the file in a path; second, require controls whether a file has already been run to avoid duplicating the work.

https://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html

Be careful with user input, make sure the user is only allowed to load whitelisted files.